# Is there any way to export a BigQuery table's schema as YAML?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I understand we can export table schema info in JSON format by 'bq show' command in GCP, but don't know how to export to yaml file.

Is there any way to convert schema info to yaml file automatically? Our table's structure is a bit complicated and target tables are so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the tool [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) for this task.

[Homepage of yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)

Example:

```bash
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] | yq -p json -o yaml
```

This command pipes the output of the `bq` command to `yq` which reads the `json`-input and exports to `yaml`.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt and perfect answer!! 
It really works for us. You saved my day!!!